# Custom IEEE 802.11 packets with pi3

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I recently downloaded the [nexmon](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon)
firmware patch for the raspi3 to be able to run my wifi chip in promiscuous mode.
After downloading this patch I am able to sniff packets and proceed to analyze them with Wireshark.  Now, I am trying to be able to send custom Beacon packets with the built-in receiver. According to some online resources, I can `aireplay-ng -9 wlan0` to see if my card is able to do this.  When I run the command I get the following results

```
    17:29:28 Trying to broadcast probe request...
    17:29:30 No Answer...
```

My question is: Is the nexmon firmware patch enough to be able to transmit custom wifi packets or is this the limits of the hardware?

Comment: This is easiest enough to test, run `tcpdump --interface <your interface> -w some_capture.pcap` . Fire up wireshark (or post it here) and open the capture to check that it's transmitted. I was messing around with this a week ago and I realized I was broadcasting packets without the proper header so they were showing up as the wrong proto. It'd be best to use another computer to capture packets (in monitor mode again) but I know good wifi cards are sometimes hard to come by.

Comment: I ran the command with the chip in monitor mode.  What exactly am I looking for in the capture file?

Comment: You're looking for the broadcast packet that you transmitted. Are you familiar with wireshark? You'll probably want to filter to just packets emitted by your device so you aren't bogged down by the general wireless noise.